# How to convert String to Int in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am working on a console application in Kotlin where I accept multiple arguments in `main()` function

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // validation & String to Integer conversion
}
```

I want to check whether the `String` is a valid integer and convert the same or else I have to throw some exception.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Use `String.toInt()`, wrap it in `try`-`catch` and handle the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I see there is no `String.toInt()` available.

Comment: It's not a static method, you have to call `toInt()` on your `String` instances. For example `args[0].toInt()`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Still working with the try-catch block.

Comment: You can also use [`toIntOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html) to get a `Int?` result, that way you don't have to use try-catch.

Comment: @HardCoder see my answer below for an example.

Comment: Great mention @zsmb13. Yes, this helps to eliminate the need for the `try-catch`.

Comment: please see the documentation https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You could call `toInt()` on your `String` instances:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for (str in args) {
        try {
            val parsedInt = str.toInt()
            println("The parsed int is $parsedInt")
        } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
            // not a valid int
        }
    }
}
```

Or `toIntOrNull()` as an alternative:

```
for (str in args) {
    val parsedInt = str.toIntOrNull()
    if (parsedInt != null) {
        println("The parsed int is $parsedInt")
    } else {
        // not a valid int
    }
}
```

If you don't care about the invalid values, then you could combine `toIntOrNull()` with the safe call operator and a scope function, for example:

```
for (str in args) {
    str.toIntOrNull()?.let {
        println("The parsed int is $it")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37):

Actually, there are several ways:

Given:

```
// aString is the string that we want to convert to number    
// defaultValue is the backup value (integer) we'll have in case of conversion failed

var aString: String = "aString"     
var defaultValue : Int    = defaultValue
```

Then we have:

| Operation | Successful operation | Unsuccessful Operation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aString.toInt() | Numeric value | NumberFormatException |
| aString.toIntOrNull() | Numeric value | null |
| aString.toIntOrNull() ?: defaultValue | Numeric value | defaultValue |

If `aString` is a valid integer, then we will get is numeric value, else, based on the function used, see a result in column `Unsuccessful Operation`.

Comment: A table is not easy to understand. Please, add column titles. What is true and  false?

Comment: Hi CoolMind, the first row is column title, it answers the question (numberString is a valid number) is true or false

Comment: Sorry, I again understood the table not so easily, so edited the answer.

Answer (score 20):

```
val i = "42".toIntOrNull()
```

Keep in mind that the result is nullable as the name suggests.

Answer (score 7):

As suggested above, use `toIntOrNull()`.

> Parses the string as an [Int] number and returns the result
> or `null` if the string is not a valid representation of a number.

```
val a = "11".toIntOrNull()   // 11
val b = "-11".toIntOrNull()  // -11
val c = "11.7".toIntOrNull() // null
val d = "11.0".toIntOrNull() // null
val e = "abc".toIntOrNull()  // null
val f = null?.toIntOrNull()  // null
```

Answer (score 7):

If you actually have a `String`, call `toInt()` on it:

```
val myInt = myString.toInt()
```

Are you actually sure it's a `String`, though? If you're iterating over a single `String`, you don't get instances of `String` of length 1 (as you might expect if you're used to another language, ie, Python), but instances of `Char`, in which case you want to use `digitToInt()` instead:

```
val myInt = myChar.digitToInt()
```

Comment: Why the `toString()` call? The asker already has a string to work with.

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 4):

I use this util function:

```
fun safeInt(text: String, fallback: Int): Int {
    return text.toIntOrNull() ?: fallback
}
```

Comment: same can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54718406/2987755

Answer (score 4):

**In Kotlin:**

Simply do that

```
val abc = try {stringNumber.toInt()}catch (e:Exception){0}
```

In catch block you can set default value for any case string is not converted to "Int".

Answer (score 2):

i would go with something like this.

```
import java.util.*

fun String?.asOptionalInt() = Optional.ofNullable(this).map { it.toIntOrNull() }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val intArgs = args.map {
        it.asOptionalInt().orElseThrow {
            IllegalArgumentException("cannot parse to int $it")
        }
    }

    println(intArgs)
}
```

this is quite a nice way to do this, without introducing unsafe nullable values.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am a newbie in Kotlin, can you please add some comments to explain the code provided? that might also help others

Comment: This is just a longer slower way to write `it.toIntOrNull() ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("cannot parse to int $it")`.

Answer (score 1):

add (?) before fun toInt()

```js
val number_int = str?.toInt()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Direct Change by using readLine()!!.toInt()

Example:

```
fun main(){

    print("Enter the radius = ")
    var r1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var area = (3.14*r1*r1)
    println("Area is $area")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## toInt()

You can call `toInt()` on a `String` to turn it into an Integer.

```kt
val number_int = str.toInt()
```

If it cannot be converted, it will throw a `NumberFormatException` error.

You could put it in a `try-catch` block:

```kt
try {
    val strVal = "IamNotanInteger"
    val intVal = strVal.toInt()
    println(intVal)
} catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
    println("This String is not convertible.")
}
```

## toIntOrNull()

`toIntOrNull()` will also convert a `String` into an `Integer`, but it will return `null` instead of throwing an error.

```kt
fun main() {
    val strVal = "246b"
    val intVal = strVal.toIntOrNull()
    println(intVal) // null
}
```

## Integer.parseInt()

Here’s how to use the parseInt() method to convert Kotlin String to Int.

```kt
fun main() {
    val strVal = "246"
    val intVal = Integer.parseInt(strVal)
    println(intVal) // 246
}
```

## Non-Decimal System

You can pass a radix into the `toInt()` and `toIntOrNull()` methods:

```kt
fun main() {
    val base16String = "3F"
    val base16Int = base16String.toInt(16)
    // String Interpolation
    println("$base16Int") // 63 (If I did the maths correct...)
}
```

Useful Links

- [tutorialkart](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin/kotlin-string-to-int/#gsc.tab=0)
- [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/string-to-int)
- [delftstack](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/kotlin/kotlin-string-to-int/)

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getIntValueFromString(value : String): Int {
    var returnValue = ""
    value.forEach {
        val item = it.toString().toIntOrNull()
        if(item is Int){
            returnValue += item.toString()
        }

    }
    return returnValue.toInt()

}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what the code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.