# How to convert character to its integer value in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to convert an string to its integer value in Kotlin, using the `toInt()` function that i found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570262/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-kotlin), but I'm getting the ascii value instead.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
var input = "8569 2478 0383 3437"

val regex = "[^0-9]".toRegex()
var value = regex.replace(input, "")

val iterator = value.iterator()

var sum : Int = 0
var v : Int
for((index, value) in iterator.withIndex()){
    if(index % 2 == 0){
        var v = value.toInt() * 2 
        if(v > 9) v -= 9

        print("$v:$value ")
        sum += v
    }else{
        print("$value ")
        sum += value.toInt()
    }
}
```

executing this code above, this is the printed numbers

```
103:8 5 99:6 9 91:2 4 101:7 8 87:0 3 103:8 3 93:3 4 93:3 7
```

and I was expecting some like this

```
8:8 5 6:6 9 2:2 4 7:7 8 0:0 3 8:8 3 3:3 4 3:3 7
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note**: I have updated this answer because Kotlin 1.5 has a function to do this directly.

In your loop, `value` is a `Char`, and [`toInt()` on Char returns its character number](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/to-int.html). Therefore, you'll have perform a conversion to get its digit representation.

Starting in Kotlin 1.5, you can use [`digitToInt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/digit-to-int.html) to accomplish this:

```
var v = value.digitToInt()
```

Before Kotlin 1.5, we would need to convert to a `String` and then an `Int`:

```
var v = value.toString().toInt() * 2
```

Comment: because the input is a String, I tough that the iterator value stayed as string; thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting the JVM, you can use [Character.getNumericValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)):

```
val v = Character.getNumericValue(value) * 2
```

so there is no need to do two casts.

If you want to be platform independent, go with Todd's answer.