# Kotlin String to Int or zero (default value)

Tags: kotlin

How can I covert `String` to `Int` in Kotlin and if it can't be then return 0 (default value).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert String to Int in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570262/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-kotlin)

Comment: That qustion doesn't cover making default value and this is point of this one. It is covered in answers but I think this can help some people. I don't think it's duplicate but if more people mark it so I'll delete this post.

Comment: the reason why I flagged your question is because it's covered in one of the answers to that question, as you said. Let's make the community decide :)

Answer (score 9):

I think the best solution is to tell value is `Int` and use Elvis operator to assign value 0 if it can't be converted.

```
val a:String="22"
val b:Int = a.toIntOrNull()?:0//22
val c:String="a"
val d:Int = c.toIntOrNull()?:0//0
```

Answer (score 7):

To make code more concise you can create [Extension Function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

```
fun String?.toIntOrDefault(default: Int = 0): Int {
    return this?.toIntOrNull()?:default
}
```