# How to use parseInt in kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, parseint

I making fun increase, decrease for item count. I want make count.text plus "T" Character. when I tried to make code like this.
 error code: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1T"
How can I solve this problem? Any one can help??

```
   fun increaseInteger() {

        var count = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.integer_number)
        count.text=intent.getStringExtra("case")+"T"
        var countResult = parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("case")+"T")
        var countValue = countResult+1
        if (countValue >= 1 && !decrease.isEnabled) { decrease.isEnabled = true}
        intent.putExtra("result",countValue)
        display(countValue)
    }

    fun decreaseInteger() {

        var count = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.integer_number)
        count.text=intent.getStringExtra("case")+"T"
        var countResult = parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("case")+"T")
        var countValue = countResult-1
        if (countValue <= 1) {decrease.isEnabled = false }
        intent.putExtra("result",countValue)
           display(countValue)
    }
```

Comment: Well the error message indicates what the problem is: you add the char "T" to a number and try to parse that to an int. You should parse the count to an it first, increment it and AFTERWARDS add the char T.

Comment: thanks for u r comment, I already try it many times . but i dont know how to solve it .

Comment: Why do you add T in the first place to your int? Try removing the T and your code should be good to go :)

Comment: What is the actual input and how does the desired output look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert String to Int in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570262/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-kotlin)

Comment: I need add 'T' .. it is duty. coz of project work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The API is pretty straightforward:

```
"123".toInt() // returns 123 as Int
"123T".toInt() // throws NumberFormatException
"123".toIntOrNull() // returns 123 Int?
"123T".toIntOrNull() // returns null as Int?
```

So if you know your input might not be parseable to an Int, you can use `toIntOrNull` which will return null if the value was not parseable. It allows to use further nullability tools the language offers, e.g.:

```
input.toIntOrNull() ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("$input is not a valid number")
```

(This example uses the [elvis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253107/what-does-do-in-kotlin-elvis-operator/48254829#48254829) operator to handle the undesired null response of `toIntOrNull`, the alternative would involve a try/catch around `toInt`)

Answer (score 2):

> You can use these

```
val str = "12345"
val str_new = "12345B"
str.toInt() // returns 123 as Int
str_new.toInt() // throws NumberFormatException
str.toIntOrNull() // returns 123 Int?
str_new.toIntOrNull() // returns null as Int?
```