# How can I read an int to use in a for loop?

Tags: kotlin, for-loop, generics

How can I read an integer value from the user to use in the range of a `for` loop?

```
fun main() {
    var n = readLine()
    for (i in 1..n) {
      var (a, b) = readLine()!!.split(' ')
      println(a.toInt() + b.toInt())
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to convert String to Int in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50570262/208273)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.toInt() function to achieve this (the same thing that you doing in later lines).

Like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val n = readLine()!!.toInt()
    for (i in 1..n) {
      val (a, b) = readLine()!!.split(' ')
      println(a.toInt() + b.toInt())
    }
}
```

Also, you can replace your `var`s with `val`s since they are not changed anywhere.